# Can Get-AzWebApp get connection string information if held separate from web.cofig

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to use the `Get-AzWebApp` PowerShell command to get a list of azure app services and then read the configuration/connection strings from each one. Does this still work if the web.config of each app service has the connection strings stored in a separate file, so e.g. in web.config we have

```
<connectionStrings configSource="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

Would we expect this to work still?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this still work if the web.config of each app service has the connection strings stored in a separate file, so e.g. in web.config we have
> **<connectionStrings configSource="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" / >**
> Would we expect this to work still?

Currently it is not possible. Fetch the connection strings from files is not possible in an app service.

In a **PowerShell** we cannot edit or add bulk connection strings and app settings using files.

We can add the connection String/ App Settings it will be added like key value. So, whatever we add in an App Settings we can get that as **string** value.